# My Raspberry Pi cannot connect to my wifi

Tags: wifi

I guess it's because I logged out of it once by accident. and the Pi now cannot get any Wi-Fi network and shows "no AP found scanning".

I have tried to do the command `sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0` and it shows "No wireless interfaces found".

I also tried (`sudo`) `iwlist wlan0 scan` and it shows "No scan results".

Can anyone help?

Comment: after I changing "iface wlan0 inet manual" to "iface wlan0 inet dhcp" now the network shows"No wireless interfaces found" only

Comment: and another question is I can't get my ip address by using command of "ifconfig". no ip address shows there. and essid shows off/any if i input iwconfig

Answer (score 1):

the result is that there is something wrong on my hardware...

Comment: Then this likely won't help anyone. Update your original question, or delete it

Answer (score 0):

I see what you have tried, and would suggest you use this command:

```
sudo wicd-curses
```

It will help you figure out your connections.  Point to the one you want and use config to get the password and router IP entered.  Make sure you're on the right interface under Prefs.  Then try Connect.

As you make changes, use ifconfig to see the results.

Sometimes a reboot is required before they take hold, since curses is changing the configuration files.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I haven't installed wicd and there's no network so ......:(((

Answer (score 0):

After booting up you pi go to the upper right of your display and click on the Wi-Fi icon enter your Wi-Fi info; ie your ssid and password and you will be on your way.
If your pi does have Wi-Fi then attach a Wi-Fi dongle before inputting the info.